How to fix errors after updating WPF app to .NET 8
I am attempting to update a WPF app from .NET Framework 4.7.2 to .NET 8.  Using the Upgrade option in Visual Studio, I have updated all of my projects and resolved my dependencies.
What I can't figure out is why I am getting several errors that look like this:


XamlC error XFC0000: Cannot resolve type "Application".
XamlC error XFC0000: Cannot resolve type "Window".
XamlC error XFC0000: Cannot resolve type "UserControl".


Googling this brings back results for .NET Maui an Xamarin, I don't think either of these apply to me.
How do I fix these errors?  Am I missing something?

I was about to write, "Are you sure this isn't a MAUI or Xamarin project?" I assume you've tried all the usual steps - clearing every bin/obj folder, even clearing all the hidden .vs folders, etc? Also all the right projects need the <UseWPF>true</UseWPF> property in addition to <TargetFramework>net8.0-windows</TargetFramework>. That's everything obvious that comes to mind.

I had forgotten about the .vs folders.  I went back and deleted all of the bin, obj and .vs folders and double checked the UseWPF tag.  Still havet the same problem.  :(

Bah. Only other thing I can think of is your Visual studio install itself. In VS install under "Workloads" you need ".NET desktop development". Maybe a longshot but I wonder if you have MAUI installed (hence it's trying to compile XAML using XamlC, which is definitely a MAUI thing) but not the WPF prereqs, so it's falling back to the MAUI compiler. In .NET Framework WPF was built in but with Core and higher you have to specifically include it.

After double checking the install, I have verified that I definitely do not have MAUI installed.  But, your comment about making sure the .NET framework WPF was included led me to take a long, hard look at the .csproj file.  I ended up getting rid of everything and adding back in only the bare necessities.  It seems to work now.  If you want to type up an official answer about that, I'll be happy to accept it since you took the time to help me.

I don't know how you updated it, but when I went from .NET Framework to .NET, I found the only reliable way to do it was to manually recreate the projects in .NET 5.  Just visually comparing the "updated" version to the "clean" one it seemed the right way to go.

Great! Glad to help and much appreciated.

Converting a WPF project from .NET Framework to .NET Core/6/7/8/etc. can be a little tricky because while the code and XAML shouldn't need changes, the project files are completely different as are the output files.
If having any trouble making the conversion (whether manual or automated), these would be the standard troubleshooting steps to try:

Clear out all bin/obj directories and the hidden .vs directory(s) and restart VS.
Ensure the right tooling is installed in Visual Studio. The ".NET desktop development" workload is required and should be sufficient.
Ensure that every relevant csproj file has the <UseWPF>true</UseWPF> property in addition to <TargetFramework>netX.0-windows</TargetFramework>.
If your .NET Core WPF csproj files started as .NET Framework projects, it's quite possible either you or the conversion tool missed items that were specific to .NET Framework and no longer apply to .NET Core. The .NET Framework project files were a lot more verbose and bespoke to the platform, so there may be obsolete leftover items in there that are interfering with the build.
Not directly part of the question, but worth mentioning - when distributing your app, don't forget your users will either need the .NET Windows Desktop runtime, or you'll need to publish your app with the "self-contained" deployment mode so that all needed runtime assemblies are included (which unfortunately adds on the order of 100MB to your distribution size). This wasn't an issue with .NET Framework because WPF was a standard part of the Framework and Framework was almost always already installed on newer Windows machines.

